# Directive on ng-repeat images only pulls information about the first image

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, image

My intention is to dynamically add a class based on the height and width so that it will fit inside of a div. This directive here is pulling the height and width, then adds the class. The problem I am running into is that it takes the information for the first image and uses that data to add classes to all the rest. So all images are returned with 'portrait-image' even though they need 'landscape-image'.

Here's my directive

```
function dynamicImageDirective(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.on('load', function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var w = $(this).width(),
                        h = $(this).height();
                    if (w > h) {
                        elem.addClass('landscape-image');
                    } else {
                        elem.addClass('portrait-image');
                    }
                },0);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

And the repeat:

```
 <div class="fullWidth" ng-repeat="gallery in public.galleries">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 right">
        <div class="fullWidth display-inlineBlock verticalCenterDiv" style="height: 325px; padding: 0px;">
            <span class="helper"></span>
            <img ng-click="openLightboxModal($index)" class="vertical-middle" number="{{$index}}" ng-show="gallery.image_url" ng-src="{{gallery.image_url}}" dynamic-image="gallery">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your `ng-repeat` code

Comment: Or it could be that w and h are both zero and it's defaulting to the else part of the conditional.  I would check that w and h are being calculated correctly.  There is nothing I can see about the directive that would cause it to interfere with other directives.

Comment: Also add a codepen / plunkr to illustrate.

Comment: So w and h return 1314 and 906 respective each time. The images loaded are different each time though. one in particular is portrait, yet it returns the value of the first image and gives the outcome to each of the images.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by changing it to 'bind' instead of 'on load'.

```
function dynamicImageDirective(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.bind('load', function() {
                var w = this.width;
                var h = this.height;
                if (w > h) {
                    $(this).addClass('landscape-image');
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('portrait-image');
                }
            });
            elem.bind('error', function(){

            });
        }
    }
}
```